# How do you turn a string input into a matrix?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble turning my input into a matrix. My input includes the elements of a matrix, separated by commas, and the rows separated by semicolons.

Example input: `"1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9"`

How could I use this string to construct the related 3x3 matrix?

Comment: what have you tried so far? let us help you. Basically, all you need is a double use of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 2):

np.matrix will do the trick:

```
np.matrix("1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9".replace(",",' '))                                                                                                                                     

matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])
```